# Set properties on an array, funky array returned in chrome/node/canary?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

From the function below should the array returned from the chrome console be displayed like this?

```
[ name: 'Mike', age: 60, role: 'director' ]
```

When I type the array in the chrome console I get an expected syntax error returned. I understand I'm setting properties on an empty array but I thought the array wouldn't be display like this
`[ name: 'Mike', age: 60, role: 'director' ]`

Is this chrome trying to help me out by telling me the properties?

Entering the function in jsfiddle, firefox and safari returns an empty array but chrome displays the properties on an array.

```js
var object = {
  name: 'Mike',
  age: 60,
  role: 'director'
}
var array = []

function test_reduce(object) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce(function(array, key) {
    array[key] = object[key]
    return array;
  }, array)
}

var dummy_1 = test_reduce(object)
console.log(dummy_1)

function test_Loop(object) {
  for (var key in object) {
    array[key] = object[key]
  }
  return array;
}

var dummy_1 = test_reduce(object)
console.log(dummy_1)
console.log(test_Loop(object))
```

I'm using

```
Chrome Version 61.0.3119.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)
Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
Node.js v7.7.4
Safari Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4)
Firefox 53.0.3 (64-bit)
```

Comment: Arrays and objects are not interchangeable.

Comment: An array is still an object and thus, can have properties like an object. At a guess, I'd just say it's the way Chrome is choosing to show you the array and its properties.

Comment: If you check the expanded view in FF (click on the *Array* link in the console), you'll get the same properties displayed as in the one of chrome dev-tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array returned is same in all the cases, although while other browsers do not list the properties of an array by default, chrome does (Specific to scenarios when empty array is used as an map). For example if you click on the empty array returned on Firefox console, it will list down the properties you have added.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are specialized objects. While chrome will let you enter non-numeric keys, many other browsers will behave erratically. Perhaps you are mixing PHP arrays with JavaScript arrays.

PHP arrays are more equivalent to JavaScript objects. JavaScript arrays are more similar to c/java style arrays (technically, it's a linked list).